# What does 'under subsection' mean in the following clause?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> 40. (4) The Secretary of State may not make an order *under subsection* (2) if he is satisfied that the order would make a person stateless.

What does *under subsection* mean in this context?

Comment: It seems this quotation is subsection (4) and refers to subsection (2) that appears just two items before this.

Comment: Could you please tell us where that citation is from? Where are those citations from? Please tell us the name of where you got that text from, and if applicable, also a link. If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

under - in reference to, by the details specified, in that section

"under subsection (2)" means there is some rule in that subsection which allows this order to be made.

Comment: It's been really helpful. Thank you for the valuable answer.

Answer (score 4):

Subsection 40(2) of the [British Nationality Act](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1981/61/section/40) reads:

> 40.-(2) The Secretary of State may by order deprive a person of a citizenship status if the Secretary of State is satisfied that deprivation is conducive to the public good.

So an order made under subsection (2) is one made using the power set out in this subsection.

Answer (score 0):

The Secretary of State is in public office.  They are able to issue (binding) orders or rulings on matters brought to their attention.

But, they are required to state **which** legislation, section, sub-section, and clause (or more than one) they made such a **ruling**.

This is because the ruling can also be challenged (and potentially overturned), based on either the (incorrect) **applicability** of the section (sub-section or clause) or on more general guiding principles: greater public good, secrecy/privacy laws, precedence (past cases), or personal discretion (changing their mind).